# Pandas DataFrame Handling Duplicates in Lookup DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have 2 Excel files that I import into DataFrames. One is my main data set and the other is a lookup data set. I process both files to create the `CN ON` column, which becomes my key. The look up data set gets processed and I remove duplicates after the processing. I want to bring in the `Code` column to the main data set. If one `CN ON` is associated with multiple `Code` values, then assign it to `'Multiple'`. If the `FO = 'R1'`, then make the `Code = 'R1'`. If there is no code value for the associated `CN ON`, then make `Code = 'NONE'`. I apologize for any incorrect terminology as well!

**Main Data Set**

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CN ON': ['WD-D5','JF-04','P5','PK-E4','UL-G8','MD-ZZ'],
                   'D1': ['D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6']
        })
```

**Lookup Data Set**

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CN': ['WD','JG','P5','PK','PK','UL','UL'],
                   'ON': ['D5','04','','E4','E4','G8','G8'],
                   'FO': ['A','A','A','A','A','R','R'],
                   'Code': ['D1','YZ','YZ','HY','PB','SA','SA'],
                   'CN ON': ['WD-D5','JF-04','P5','PK-E4','PK-E4','UL-G8','UL-G8']    
                   })
```

**Current**

`CN ON` is my key and then `Code` is the value I am looking up. I was trying modify `df2` before joining the data sets together. If `FO = 'R1'`, then set `Code = 'R1'`. If one `CN ON` associated with different `Code` values, then assign `Code = 'MULTIPLE'` for all instances.

That would then yield the below DataFrame.

[image: Updated Code]

Then, I would remove the duplicate rows which should yield a column of unique `CN ON` values. Then, I would join the DataFrames together.

```
#Remove duplicates
df2.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Unique list of `CN ON` with `Code` lookup.

[image]

```
#Left join the two DataFrames, with the Main Data Set being on the left on the 'CN ON' column
combined = pd.merge(df,df2[['CN ON','Code']], on = 'CN ON',how='left')

#If no 'Code' exists, then replace the 'NaN' values with 'NONE'
combined.update(combined[['Code']].fillna('NONE'))
```

**Desired Result**

[image]

I am definitely open to other solutions, but this is what logically made sense in my mind. I am having trouble in modifying `df2` to update the `Code` column with either the `Code` or `'Multiple'`. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated! I've been learning a lot in this process, and I've received a significant amount of help for StackOverflow. I appreciate everyone's patience!

Comment: Why isn't UL multiple?

Comment: What are you trying to do...simply? What is your current output and what is your current code...and what is your desired output?

Comment: ```'UL-G8'``` is not multiple because it is only associated to 1 code value, which is ```'SA'``` originally. However, it should get reassigned to ```'R1'``` due to ```FO = 'R1'```. Then the ```drop_duplicates``` function should take care of that.

Comment: @BlackFox what I really need to do is modify ```df2```. If ```FO = 'R1'```, then ```Code = 'R1'```. If ```'CN ON'``` is associated with multiple ```Code``` values, then ```Code = 'Multiple'``` for every instance. Otherwise, ```Code = Code```. For example, ```'PK-E4'``` shows up twice and has two different codes associated with it. Therefore, it gets assigned ```'Multiple'``` for both instances. Sorry for the lengthy explanation.

Comment: Why not create 2 new df’s. 1 a list of code = code and 2 a list of code = multiple. Now ask your self the question again...what do i want from df2 and df3 and df4. Then ask stackoverflow again. I think your question here is more about how do i think about designing a solution.  Let’s get some new examples of your work then a clear requirement for future work (stackoverflow help).

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was easier to split up the DataFrame or just keep it together. It's really just about assigning the proper ```Code``` to the each ```CN ON``` so I can have a unique lookup list. Should I edit this post entirely? I don't want to remove any information if someone else has looked at it and is designing a solution.

Comment: Think through it...so if you do the df2, df3,df4 approach i spoke to in my last comment...you can then do an IF TRUE on both df3 and df4. Add a new COL called Multiple to df2. IF the row is true for this new COL in df2 then display text Multiple. If false for new COL df2 multiple display text of code COL. The new requirements goal is to create a new version of df2 showing if each row of data shows in df3 or df4. If in df3 return 1 , if in df3 return 0. If you where to say create a function for each logic calculation....you could call one function MULTIPLY and the other CODE_AS_TEXT.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just do it all in the same DataFrame instead of creating 2 new ones? Couldn't you apply that same logic all on one DataFrame and just create 2 new columns? One column ```Multiple``` and the other column ```Updated Code```. I will need to think through it, since I get stuck on how to actually flag if it should be ```'Multiple'```. If FO = 'R1' then Code = 'R1', else if Count(CN ON) > 1 then Code = 'Multiple else Code = Code. That's the logic I see it as.

Comment: Maybe you can...but how do you explain the DataFrame Transformation? How do you learn it? How do you understand how to use it? My approach is a way to test the logic, explain the requirements and storyboard an implementation of all requirements. A better developer can then offer a better way;)

Comment: That makes sense. I definitely want and need a better understanding of Python and DataFrames. Let me see how far I can get with your proposed or another solution. If I can implement it in any way instead of the "ideal" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) 
instead of `merge`. To do this you would first have to create the appropriate seire by removing duplicates and writing MULTIPLE and R1 where necessary:

```
r=df['FO'].eq('R')
d=df['CN ON'].duplicated(keep=False)

#Creating column with MULTIPLE in duplicated values and R1 where FO is R
df['mapper']=df['Code'].mask(d,'MULTIPLE').mask(r,'R1')
#df['mapper']=df['Code'].mask(d|r,np.where(r,'R1','MULTIPLE')) #ALTERNATIVE

#Creating Mapper with unique values
mapper=df.drop_duplicates('CN ON').set_index('CN ON')['mapper']

#remove mapper column
df=df.drop('mapper',axis=1) 

# Creating Code using Series.map
df2['Code']=df2['CN ON'].map(mapper).fillna('NONE')

#Show the result
print(df2)


   CN ON  D1      Code
0  WD-D5  D1        D1
1  JF-04  D2        YZ
2     P5  D3        YZ
3  PK-E4  D4  MULTIPLE
4  UL-G8  D5        R1
5  MD-ZZ  D6      NONE
```

Comment: This is great! I've been playing around with this solution trying to understand it better. I really appreciate it! This is getting me exactly what I need. I have not used the mapper function, so I'm trying to figure out your solution entirely still.

Comment: I am glad to help you!